# WHM/CPanel Forensics on Linux Server

Tags: security, cpanel

What are some potential sources of forensics related to an intrusion on WHM/CPanel on a Linux server?

I'm aware of

- `/var/log`
- `/usr/local/apache/logs/`
- `/usr/local/cpanel/logs/`
- `/usr/local/apache/domlogs`.

Anything else I can look into? Also, what's a good way to parse/interpret this data?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm aware of /var/log, /usr/local/apache/logs/, /usr/local/cpanel/logs/, /usr/local/apache/domlogs.

Any logs that are on a compromised server should be considered suspect and likely worthless for forensics.

> Also, what's a good way to parse/interpret this data

To a large extent it will depend upon which log (they all have different formats), use a mk1 eyeball and experience but note my comment about the value of logs on a compromised server.